# Json format issue in rails 1.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, format

I know rails 1.2.3 is stale now but i have got a project in rails 1.2.3 to work on. I want to output the result in json format. i am using

render :json => @result.to_json and return

it gives me {success: "false"}

instead, i want {"success": "false"}

I cant go for an upgrade as on now.

Please suggest.

Comment: You've asked 19 questions, but haven't accepted an answer to any of them. Please go back and accept answers to your previous questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `ActiveSupport::JSON.unquote_hash_key_identifiers = false` to `environment.rb`.

Comment: Above solution worked well on my local where i have multiple rails version staring from 1.2.3 to Rails 3 exist. But when i try this on my phusion passenger based server it says unidentified constant Active support. Configuration on server: Ruby 1.8.6 and Rails 2.3.5, 2.3.8

Comment: Make sure rails is loaded first. For Rails 2, you can move the code from `environment.rb` to an initializer.

Comment: Which code? Your solution is not clear . Please explain. My app is developed in rails 1.2.3

Comment: You're saying the error is showing up in Rails 2. The solution is only valid for Rails 1.2.

Comment: Solution - Adding the line "ActiveSupport::JSON.unquote_hash_key_identifiers = false" at the end of environment.rb worked